# How can I display (echo) the selected value in php?

Tags: php, echo

How can i display the value from the mysql_query or save the value in a variable ? At the moment I get Resource id #4.

```
$currentpointsquery = "SELECT user_points FROM points WHERE user_id = '$user_id';";
$currentpointsquery2 = mysql_query($currentpointsquery);
echo(currentpointsquery2);
```

Comment: Please show your existing code.

Comment: 0. open the hangar cause the plane is flying in... 1. don't use mysql_* functions, 2. output particular columns, not the resource, $currentpointsquery['user_points']; 3. don't change code after you've pasted it

Comment: remove the ; at '$user_id';" in the first line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo($currentpointsquery2);
```

Here you are trying to print a mysql [resource variable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php) instead of the values contained within the resource it references. The `mysql_fetch_array()` function returns a row from a recordset as an associative array and/or a numeric array. So try with

```
echo $currentpoints[0];
```

or

```
 echo $currentpoints['user_points'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
$currentpointsquery = "SELECT user_points FROM points WHERE user_id = '$user_id'";
$currentpointsquery2 = mysql_query($currentpointsquery);
$currentpoints = mysql_fetch_array($currentpointsquery2);
echo $currentpoints['user_points'];
```